# Find CheckBox Inside a repeater in another button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have two nested repeater and a check box inside that, like this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptInterestCategory" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptInterestCategory_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptInterests" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptInterests_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbInterest" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="cbInterest_CheckedChanged" Data-Id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %>' Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name") %>' />

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <hr/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Now on another button click event I want to find  which all checkboxes(`cbInterest` )are checked and need to get the value inside it. What will be the correct approach to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you would loop through them is to first get a reference to the nested Repeater:

```
Repeater rptInterests = (Repeater)rptInterestCategory.FindControl("rptInterests");
```

And then you can loop through the data items, find the checkbox, and get the value of the CheckBox:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptInterests.Items)
{
    CheckBox cbInterest = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("cbInterest");
    bool isChecked = cbInterest.Checked;
}
```

Comment: Error 11 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Athul Sorry about that, forget to cast those CheckBox and Repeater control's. I've updated the code.